# Rails4 + OmniAuth で、Twitter 経由のアプリ認証エラーが発生する

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, twitter

Rails 初心者です。

[コチラ](http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20140805/1407200400)の記事を参考に Rails で OAuth による Twitter ログインを実装しています。
ひと通りの設定が終わり、 Twitter に飛んだ後「連携アプリを認証」ボタンをおして
サイトに戻ってくるときに、以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。

[image: エラー画面]

調べてみると、原因としましては、 Rails のコントローラには
予期しない値を受け入れないようにするための仕組みがあり
Rails 4.x からは外部から渡ってくるパラメータのホワイトリストの定義方法が変更となり

```
params.require(:hoge).permit(:fuga, :piyo)
```

などと記述するようになっているということを理解したのですが
コントローラで受け取ったパラメータをどのようにして `User.from_omniauth()` メソッドに
渡せばいいのか分かりません。

コントローラのコードは以下になります。

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = 'welcome!'
      sign_in_and_redirect
    else
      session['devise.user_attributes'] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ActionController::Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-c-new)

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(request.env['omniauth.auth']).permit!
```

Comment: 参考になりましたm(_ _)m

Answer (score 1):

User(app/models/user.rb)を修正します。

変更前:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.username = auth.info.nickname
      user.email = auth.info.email
    end
  end
end
```

変更後:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.username = auth.info.nickname
      user.email = auth.info.email
    end
  end
end
```

参照:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399414/rails-4-1-5-omniauth-strong-parameters